# Does <source> "sizes" attribute work in Chrome for <picture> element?

Tags: html, image, responsive-images

The `<picture>` element has been working in Chrome for over a year, but I can't get the `sizes` attribute of `<source>` to work.

The following displays the correct image for the breakpoints in the media queries, but the images are displayed at their default sizes instead of using the values specified in the `sizes` attribute.

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 600px)" 
           sizes="50vw"
           srcset="img1.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 400px)"
           sizes="90vw"
           srcset="img2.jpg">
   <img src="img3.jpg" alt="my image">
</picture>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `w` descriptors when using the `sizes` attribute, otherwise it has no effect.

> Error: Bad value img1.jpg for attribute srcset on element source: No width specified for image img1.jpg. (When the sizes attribute is present, all image candidate strings must specify a width.)

https://validator.nu/

So your HTML should read:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 600px)" 
           sizes="50vw"
           srcset="img1.jpg 300w">
   <source media="(min-width: 400px)"
           sizes="90vw"
           srcset="img2.jpg 200w">
   <img src="img3.jpg" alt="my image">
</picture>
```

Though if you only have one candidate per `source`, you could use CSS instead to size the image appropriately for different breakpoints and skip `sizes`/`w`. The primary function of `sizes` is to give a hint to the browser which of the resources in `srcset` to load; that it affects the intrinsic size is more of a side-effect.